# Is there a way to create Firebase real time database event listeners?

Tags: go, firebase-realtime-database, streaming, event-listener

I am trying to integrate real time event listeners into my application that utilizes firebase realtime database.

I came across [this post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/issues/229) that discussed this but it seems that it will not be implemented in the official SDK.

I also came across [the firebase REST/Streaming endpoints](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-streaming) and was considering using this to integrate realtime listeners.

My question is, is there a recommended way to achieve this? (Websockets, callbacks, channels ect.) Is there already a library that does this so I don't have to write code from scratch to achieve this functionality?

Comment: If you use REST/Streaming endpoint, run a goroutine that parses the event stream from the response and dispatch events from that stream however you want.  There's probably an SSE client package somewhere, but it's easy enough to parse SSE using buffo.Scanner and some string matching.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials on how to best set this up? I cant seem to find any. Should I just use the http package or is there a good SSE client that people recommend?

Comment: Use the net/http client to request the stream, create a bufio.Scanner on the response body to read lines, parse the lines.  The format is simple.  There are [existing SSE clients for Go](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=server+sent+event+client&m=package), but I don't have a recommendation for one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's native web socket wire protocol is not documented. The closest you can get to the behavior of the native SDKs (outside of using those) with a public API is by using the REST Streaming API that Hiranya also linked in the Github issue. I've done this for various projects in various languages (though never in Go), and it's often a reasonable approach though slightly less efficient than the native web sockets, as it needs separate connections for reading and writing data.

To get started, I recommend checking out:

- The blog post announcing the [REST streaming API for Realtime Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/03/announcing-streaming-for-firebase-rest.html)
- The sample clients for [Python](https://github.com/googlearchive/EventSource-Examples/tree/master/python) and [Ruby](https://github.com/googlearchive/EventSource-Examples/tree/master/ruby).
- REST [SSE implementations for Go](https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+sse+go&oq=rest+sse+go).

Comment: Thanks for the response! So basically just set up a connection with the REST streaming api and parse the response? If I were to set up SSE, is there a package that you might recommend or should I use the http library in Go?

Comment: Nope, sorry, no recommendations. But when I did this in Python, I used an existing SSE implementation, and in JavaScript, rolling my own, I found that SSE is not *that* difficult once you get started (especially if you're familiar with long-polling HTTP requests).

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!